# PowerMockito mock a generic constructor

Tags: java, generics, junit, mockito, powermock

I have a class that is declared like this:

```
public class GenericFoo<T>
{
    private final Class<T> _c;
    public GenericFoo(Class<T> c)
    {
        this._c = c; 
    }
    /*
    ...
    rest is unimportant
    */
}
```

I am writing a unit test for a class, call it `SomeBar` which creates and makes use of instances of `GenericFoo`. For this test I need the constructor to always return a specific spy of `GenericFoo`.

```
    MyWebServiceResponse webServiceResponseObject = setUpTestResponseObject(1,2,3);

    GenericFoo<MyWebServiceResponse> testFoo = PowerMockito.spy(new GenericFoo<MyWebServiceResponse>(MyWebServiceResponse.class));

    PowerMockito.when(testFoo.processResponseObject(webServiceResponseObject))
            .thenAnswer(new Answer<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable
                {
                    /* details unimportant */
                }
            });
```

To ensure that `testFoo` is returned when `SomeBar` creates an instance of `GenericFoo<MyWebServiceResponse>`, I've tried this:

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(com.myCompany.GenericFoo.class)
                .withParameterTypes(MyWebServiceResponse.class)
                .withArguments(MyWebServiceResponse.class)
                .thenReturn(testFoo);
```

This causes PowerMock to produce the error:

```
org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.ConstructorNotFoundException: Failed to lookup constructor with parameter types [ com.myCompany.MyWebServiceResponse ] in class com.myCompany.GenericFoo.
...[stack trace snipped]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.myCompany.GenericFoo.(com.myCompany.MyWebServiceResponse)
```

Is there any way to get a generic constructor to return a specific object in this sort of situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of your error is that the parameter type for the constructor is just `Class` at runtime (and `Class<T>` at compile time, never `MyWebServiceResponse`).

So using

```
.withParameterTypes(Class.class)
```

should work.

Comment: That clears up the exception, although I don't think the mocking actually works: the specific instance is not returned when subsequent instances of `GenericFoo` are created, a regular instance is returned which executes different code and produces a difference result.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to use [@PrepareForTest](http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.3.5/apidocs/org/powermock/core/classloader/annotations/PrepareForTest.html) ?

Comment: Yes, it looks like that. `MyAction` is what's creating `GenericFoo` and I forgot to add it to the PrepareForTest.